# Multi-Line text split on multiple HTML elements with PUG

Tags: html, pug

I am creating a pug template and I am trying to figure out how to output multi line text BUT split on an anchor tag.

I am brand new to pug, so my knowledge is limited to a day.

header.pug

```
div.col-12
  a(href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank").
    Learn more
about safety precautions
```

Desired Output

```
<div class="col-12">
   <a href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank">Learn more</a>about safety precautions
</div>
```

But instead my text of `about safety precautions` keeps showing up inside of the `</a>` tag.

Comment: Check out the pug docs on plain text here https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html
Try using the `|` (pipe) character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want text inline you can use the `span` element which won't break the paragraph:

```
div.col-12
  span
    a(href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank").
      Learn more
  span.
    about safety precautions
```

You could also use the [pipe syntax](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html) in pug:

```
div.col-12
  a(href="https://somelink.com" target="_blank").
    Learn more
  | about safety precautions
```

Personally I prefer the span as more web developers who follow me will understand what's going on.  No real negatives to either method though.

Comment: Thanks for the insight of using a span vs just a pipe. Good explanation.